# GO : unknown flag -trimpath

Tags: go

This is my first time with GO.

```
/* hello.go  My first GOlang program */

package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        fmt.Printf("Hello World\n")
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
# command-line-arguments

/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/6g: unknown flag -trimpath
```

I am not able to understand what is the problem.

Comment: Hey thanks for the edit. I have no idea how to copy paste code. It is quite cumbersome to type four spaces before writing code.

Comment: Highlight the code you want to have formatted as code and then click the `{}` button in the editor. This will do the right thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, this is related to the way go has been installed.
See  [GOlang Some Common Errors](http://golang-basic.blogspot.fr/)

> after trying 1.3 meant “you need to unapck your .tar.gz file to /usr/local
>
> ```
> http://golang.org/doc/install#tarball
> ```
>
> One can not just install the golang 1.3 from the installer, you should try out the untar option for better results.
>
> Errors found during :
>
> ```
> brew install spiff
> go install github.com/tools/godep
>
> # github.com/kr/fs
> /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/6g: unknown flag -trimpath
> ```

So follow the [install section](http://golang.org/doc/install#tarball)

> [Download the archive](http://golang.org/dl/) and extract it into /usr/local, creating a Go tree in `/usr/local/go`.
> For example:
>
> ```
> tar -C /usr/local -xzf go$VERSION.$OS-$ARCH.tar.gz
> ```
>
> Choose the archive file appropriate for your installation. For instance, if you are installing Go version 1.3 for 64-bit x86 on Linux, the archive you want is called go1.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz.
>
> Add `/usr/local/go/bin` to the `PATH` environment variable. You can do this by adding this line to your `/etc/profile` (for a system-wide installation) or `$HOME/.profile`.
>
> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
> ```

To uninstall and start over: see [Uninstall Go](http://golang.org/doc/install#uninstall)

> To remove an existing Go installation from your system delete the go directory. This is usually `/usr/local/go` under Linux, Mac OS X, and FreeBSD or `c:\Go` under Windows.
>
> You should also remove the Go `bin` directory from your `PATH` environment variable.
> Under Linux and FreeBSD you should edit `/etc/profile` or `$HOME/.profile`. If you installed Go with the Mac OS X package then you should remove the `/etc/paths.d/go` file.

Comment: It seems like I already did so. I am getting lot of *Can't unlink already existing object* . Is there a way that I can completely unistall go and start from scratch?

Comment: I am using MAC OSx10.9

Comment: Check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/camlistore-commits/Ai4vsufGOVM), you should delete `/usr/local/go` and start over.

Comment: @mousecoder I have edited the answer to include uninstall instructions.