# Go: How to explicitly link to OS X frameworks when building?

Tags: macos, go

When trying to get and build goose on OS X 10.10.3 using `go get bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/cmd/goose` I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_SecKeychainItemExport", referenced from:
  _FetchPEMRoots in 000001.o
"_SecTrustCopyAnchorCertificates", referenced from:
  _FetchPEMRoots in 000001.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I figure this error being due to the Security framework in OS X not being linked. Some possibly related info here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11258

So, how can I link to this library explicitly? Or is there something else I am missing?

Thankful for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `go build` flags to `go get`. So:

```
go get -f -u -ldflags "-framework Security" bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/cmd/goose
```

will force the download and link against Security framework.

Comment: Good idea. For some reason the framework flag doesn't seem to be recoginzed for me though..  "/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/6l: unknown flag -framework"

Comment: There are problems with brew installation, read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25095603/560382 Try uninstall go, and re-install it from the oficial osx installer (or source code)

Comment: Actually, re-installing Go from the official package solved the issue for me. I didn't get the -framework flag to work, but I didn't need it. Goose builds fine now. Thanks a lot, mate!